# Zoom in and out Particular layer in the stage using kineticjs?

Tags: kineticjs

i have four layers in stage.
Is that possible to zoom in and out a particular layer in a stage?
I looking forward your answer.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

A Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/qSnXQ/

Yes, an individual layer can be scaled with `layer.scale`:

```
// scale layer by 2X

layer.scale({x:2,y:2});
```

You might also want to set the scaling point using `layer.offset`:

```
// set the scaling point to [100,100] on the layer

layer.offset({x:100,y:100});
```

Setting the offset will "move" the layer up+left, so you can correct by resetting the `layer.position`

```
// since layer.offset pulled the layer up+left
// now correct by pushing the layer down+right

layer.position({x:100,y:100});
```

So scaling an individual layer at [100,100] by 2X would look like this:

```
layer.offset({x:100,y:100});
layer.position({x:100,y:100});
layer.scale({x:2,y:2});
layer.draw();
```